# Is there a tag for debugging problems with emacs initialization that is NOT related to your personal init file?

Tags: discussion, tags

I ran across [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/15056/emacs-trunk-how-to-prevent-creation-of-home-directories-in-load-path) and saw that it was only tagged with [load-path](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/load-path), when it was asking about a problem with emacs initialization, although NOT asking about a problem with `.emacs` / `init.el`. So the [init-file](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/init-file) tag doesn't seem appropriate. Is there a more appropriate tag for this situation, or should one be created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is great value in standardizing taxonomy. Or to put it in less expensive words: it is easier to understand each other when we all use the same words. Therefore I favor using the same terminology as the Emacs manual when it makes sense.

Some aspects of Emacs initialization are covered in the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/index.html) under “Entering Emacs”, “Emacs Invocation” and “Init File” but none of these aspects are relevant for this question. In the [Emacs Lisp manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/index.html), the section heading for Emacs's initialization is “[Starting Up](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Starting-Up.html#Starting-Up)”, with a subsection [Startup](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Startup-Summary.html#Startup-Summary). Hence the logical name for the applicable tag is [startup](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/startup).

We already have a tag called [start-up](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/start-up), which is a reasonable and discoverable variation.

Comment: Very reasonable, thank you.

Comment: And for debugging startup, two tags: `debugging` and `start-up`.

Answer (score -1):

How about [vanilla-emacs](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vanilla-emacs) to indicate that the question is about emacs with its default configuration? That should make it very clear, that no user configuration is part of the question.

Comment: That's not the point here. The issue that the question is about is not Emacs with its default configuration, it's what Emacs does when it starts.